# SELECTing a view shows data for the root user, but not for a different user (who has SELECT privileges)

Tags: mysql, select, privileges

Even though `SELECT` privileges are granted to our `testuser` account for `databaseName.ViewName`, `SELECT * FROM ViewName` returns all the column names, but 0 rows of data.

But when selecting the same view in SQLyog when logged in as `root`, all the data rows are shown.

We tried extracting the `SELECT` statement from the view and running it directly as `testuser`, but this resulted in the same empty table.

Is there another privilege setting we should verify? Why would we be able to `SELECT` the column names but not the data rows?

I am a low-tier employee and don't have immediate access to db privilege settings, but I will try to get them as fast as I can if requested. Thank  you in advance!

EDIT: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ViewName` as `testuser` returns `0`

Answer (score 0):

You probably defined the view to run in the name of the user invoking it, which means the user invoking it must also have at least [select privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) to the columns referenced by the view:

> When a view has been referenced, privileges for objects accessed by the view are checked against the privileges held by the view DEFINER account or invoker, depending on whether the SQL SECURITY characteristic is DEFINER or INVOKER, respectively.

If you do not want the referencing user to have direct access to the underlying table, then you need to provide a user in whose name the query runs at view create time using the [definer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-objects-security.html#stored-objects-security-definer) clause.

Comment: That sounds promising. Thank you for the reply--I'll have to check with my supervisors tomorrow what the view's `DEFINER` clause looks like (since they have root access), but I do remember seeing one and even looking at that exact "CREATE VIEW Statement" KB with a colleague while trying to troubleshoot this. Perhaps we can copy the `DEFINER` clause from a view that I *can* properly query with `testuser` over to the problematic view (or set the `DEFINER` as `root`, or as a new account with root-level `SELECT` privileges)

Comment: Ah, my new guess is the `SET_USER_ID` privilege isn't enabled for `testuser`, preventing proper use of the `DEFINER` statement (as described in the "DEFINER Attribute" KB you linked). I'll hopefully update tomorrow

Comment: It's not the testuser that needs that privilege, but the user account that is used to create the view.

Comment: Oh...oh dear. I see. Though the name of a view's creator isn't found within the `CREATE VIEW` statement itself, right? How do I find which account is the creator of a given view? (I might be able to answer this question myself when I look at it tomorrow) (For now I can probably assume it's the `root` account)

Comment: (I suppose I wrongly deduced from reading that `SELECT`ing a view implicitly `CREATE`s a temporary copy of it in that moment as the `CURRENT_USER`)

Comment: Oh...I think you meant that you need the `SET_USER_ID`/`SUPER` privilege for the user you're logged in as at the moment you create or modify a view using the `DEFINER` variable. Anyway it's very odd...We got a test server up and running with the same database. I create a new view as `root` while setting a valid account as the `DEFINER` (no warnings/errors for an invalid username after executing the query). I can select the view's data just fine as `root`, but still get 0 rows when selecting the same view as `testuser`. I even tried giving `testuser` all global permissions. Thank you anyway :/

Comment: Final spam...: Logged in as `testuser` with all global privileges, I create the same view without errors (except this time setting `DEFINER` as `CURRENT_USER`). But I *still* can't successfully `select` the view as `testuser`, that I *just* created as `testuser`! But `root` still has no problem returning the rows for the new view that it didn't even create. So there's some magical attribute that root has that `testuser` doesn't (which allows `root` to query this particular view), that I do not know how to grant `testuser`. So strange to me

Comment: It's not global privileges that you need, but privileges on the underlying tables.

Comment: Yeah I only applied all global privileges temporarily for testing purposes. When data wasn't returned even with global privileges applied, I started looking at the query itself. Turns out there was a function within the query that joined tables on the name of the logged-in database user. Every row had the username `root`, so if you execute the query as anyone else, you'll get 0 rows returned. So I had to change `JOIN ... ON ... (\`usr\`.\`Name\` = CONVERT(\`f_Username\`()USING utf8))` to `JOIN ... ON ... (\`usr\`.\`Name\` = 'root')`. Bleh. Anyway you helped me learn some important concepts ty